# what is a list of probability puzzle books that focus solely on probability?

Tags: probability, reference-request

Referring back to my problem: [Is there any surprising elementary probability problem that result in surprising solution like the Monty Hall problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610782/is-there-any-surprising-elementary-probability-problem-that-result-in-surprising)

What is a list of probability puzzle books that focus solely on probability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look at *[Probability Problems and Solutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1887187146)* or *[Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486653552)*